# Create List Item From Rich Text Field Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to take the user input text from this **div** and **input** tag I've got:

```
<input id="title" placeholder="Title (Optional)">

<div class="editor" contenteditable></div>
```

The div is a rich text field that I've put in place of a regular **textarea** tag

and create a list item inside a `<ul>` tag.

Here is the javascript I've got, but is not working...

(works just fine with regular text area, but I get nothing with the rich text form)

```
/*------POST SUBMIT JS------*/

//target all necessary HTML elements
var ul = document.getElementById('list'),
    removeAll = document.getElementById('removeAll'),
    add = document.getElementById('add');

//make something happen when clicking on 'submit'
add.onclick = function(){
  addLi(ul)
};

//function for adding items
function addLi(targetUl){
  var inputText = document.getElementsByClassName('editor').value, //grab input text (the new entry)
      header = document.getElementById('title').value, //grab title text
      li = document.createElement('li'), //create new entry/li inside ul
      content = document.createElement('div'),
      title = document.createElement('div'),
      removeButton = document.createElement('button'); //create button to remove entries

  content.setAttribute('class','content')
  title.setAttribute('class','title')
  content.innerHTML = inputText;
  title.innerHTML = header;

  if (inputText.split(' ').join(' ').length === 0) {
    //check for empty inputs
    alert ('No input');
    return false;
  }


  removeButton.className = 'removeMe'; //add class to button for CSS
  removeButton.innerHTML = 'Delete'; //add text to the remove button
  removeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeMe(this);'); //creates onclick event that triggers when entry is clicked

  li.appendChild(title); //add title textnode to created li
  li.appendChild(content); //add content textnode to created li
  li.appendChild(removeButton); //add Remove button to created li

  targetUl.appendChild(li); //add constructed li to the ul
}

//function to remove entries
function removeMe(item){
  var deleteConfirm = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');
  if (deleteConfirm){var parent = item.parentElement;
  parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent)}
};

function checkRemoval(){
  var entryConfirm = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete all entries?');
  if (entryConfirm){
    ul.innerHTML = '';
  }
};
```

[Here is the demo I'm working on](http://codepen.io/Zancrash/pen/NxpKxa)

[Here is the demo using a **textarea** tag](http://codepen.io/Zancrash/pen/yeBqKa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName('editor')` is going to return an array of elements with the class `editor`, so you can't just do `.value`, you need to get the first element in the array.

Also, since it's a div, I think you want to use `textContent`, so it'll look like this

```
var inputText = document.getElementsByClassName('editor')[0].textContent
```

Comment: This definitely worked, although the output does not include any changes made by the text box (color, size, bold/italic/underline, etc.). Any ideas on this one? Or is it better to just post a new question? Still pretty new to this site.

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't say for sure, but you could try `innerHTML` iinstead of `textContent`. You might have better luck asking a new question though

Answer (score 0):

> for the input type you have to write following into your javascript:

```
var input_val = getElementsByClassName('title').value;
```

> for the div you have to write following into your javascript:

```
var div_val = getElementsByClass('editor').value;
```

**I hope this will work**